# Create deb package from source without ./configure file

Tags: ubuntu, deb, checkinstall

How can I create a deb package for Ubuntu 14.04 from source when there is no ./configure file?

I have tried to use checkinstall but keep getting an error like

```
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

The source code I want to make a package from is the softether vpnserver

http://www.softether-download.com/files/softether/v4.19-9599-beta-2015.10.19-tree/Linux/SoftEther_VPN_Server/64bit_-_Intel_x64_or_AMD64/softether-vpnserver-v4.19-9599-beta-2015.10.19-linux-x64-64bit.tar.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and use FPM - Effing Package Manager. Instructions on how to use it can be found at https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki

There is also a nice tutorial at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-fpm-to-easily-create-packages-in-multiple-formats